# JSON encode alert message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

How do I `alert` a `json_encode()` message and reload the page? The function below only displays an undefined alert message

```
if($result1 == false)
 $response['msg'] = "Transfer failed due to a technical problem. Sorry.";
else
 $response['msg'] = "Successfully transferred";
echo json_encode($response);

$("#transfer").click(function() {
 $.ajax({
 type : "POST",
 url : "transferProduct.php",
 data : {},
 success : function(data) {                     
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   alert(data.response);    
   location.reload();         
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: there is no `data.response` object/property/value. Do a console.log(data) to see what is returned to you

Comment: Suggestion, you should separate both languages, you mixed PHP with JS.

Comment: And if you do `console.log(data);`, what output do you get? Also, your `data: {}` is empty.

Comment: there is suppose to be data inside data:{} . I am just not showing it here

Comment: ... why on earth are you not showing the structure of the thing you wish to display... how are we supposed to help you then @fypforstack? That's akin to, I'm having a problem with a book, but i'm not telling which book, or page, or what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get a undefined index `response`

Provided that your PHP script returns:

```
{
    "msg": "<your-message-here>"
}
```

In your javascript you can do it:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url: "transferProduct.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(response) {                     
        alert(response.msg);
        location.reload();         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use code in this way

transferProduct.php

```
if($result1 == false)
 $response['msg'] = "Transfer failed due to a technical problem. Sorry.";
else
 $response['msg'] = "Successfully transferred";
echo json_encode($response);
```

code page

```
$("#transfer").click(function() {
 $.ajax({
 type : "POST",
 url : "transferProduct.php",
 data : {},
 success : function(data) {                     
   datas = $.parseJSON(data);
   alert(datas.msg);    
   location.reload();         
  }
 });
});
```

or you can use $.getJSON in place of $.ajax

```
$("#transfer").click(function() {
$.getJSON("transferProduct.php",function (data){
alert(data.msg);    
   location.reload();
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should format the return to correctly identify in the background:

{"success":true,"message":"---------"}

then in JavaScript: data.message